# Define triple Integral tetrahedron truncated by oblique plane

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, computational-geometry

I am struggling on defining the integration limits of a triple integral of an oblique truncated tetrahedron.

Let's get more into the details:

I have a standard tetrahedron in a `{x,y,z}` coordinate system. Vertices coordinates are:

```
coords={{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}
```

And a generic plane with null component along the `y` direction intersecting it. Plane equation will be something like `x = a z + b`, so:

```
ThePlane = a z + b
```

In which `a` and `b` may have any Real value.

I wanna integrate a generic function `f(x,y,z)` over the region defined by the intersection of the standard tetrahedron and the plane defined above.

For example, to evaluate the volume of the region part between `{0,0,0}` and `ThePlane`, I was trying to implement something like:

```
Integrate[1,{z,0,1},{y,0,1-z},{x,0,a z + b}]
```

But this is clearly uncorrect, since `x` should also be "topped" by the plane `x=1-z-y`.

So, trying the other way around, the volume of the region part between `ThePlane` and the vertex `{1,0,0}` should be something like:

```
Integrate[1,{z,0,1},{y,0,1-z},{x,a z + b,1}]
```

But this is still wrong.

So, how should the integration limits be defined in order to correctly describe the region?

Comment: A plane with null component along the y axis would be the x-z plane. One side of your tetrahedron lies in this plane. Therefore, x=a z+b is not a plane but a line.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a plane having null normal with respect to the y-axis. For example, the I was considering the plane: 0.16 x - 0.02 z - 0.03=0.

Answer (score 1):

- The hyperplane is `0.16 x - 0.02 z - 0.03=0` which can be write as `{.16, 0, .02}.{x,y,z}==.03` and the two sides halfspace are `{.16, 0, .02}.{x,y,z}<=.03` and `{.16, 0, .02}.{x,y,z}>=.03`

```
Clear[truncated1, truncated2];
coords = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
tetra = Tetrahedron[coords];
```

then

```
truncated1 = 
  ImplicitRegion[{{.16, 0, .02} . {x, y, z} <= .03 , {x, y, 
      z} ∈ tetra}, {x, y, z}];
truncated2 = 
  ImplicitRegion[{{.16, 0, .02} . {x, y, z} >= .03, {x, y, 
      z} ∈ tetra}, {x, y, z}];
{Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ truncated1], 
 Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ truncated2]}
```

Or

```
Clear[truncated1, truncated2];

truncated1 = 
  RegionIntersection[tetra, 
   HalfSpace[{.16, 0, .02}, .03]];
truncated2 = 
  RegionIntersection[tetra, 
   HalfSpace[-{.16, 0, .02}, -.03]];
{Region[truncated1], Region[truncated2]}
{Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ truncated1], 
 Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ truncated2]}
```

> `{0.0644996, 0.102167}`.

- Animation

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Region[Hyperplane[{.16, 0, .02}, c], 
   BaseStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[.2]]], 
  Region[RegionIntersection[Tetrahedron[coords], 
    HalfSpace[-{.16, 0, .02}, -c]], BaseStyle -> Red], 
  Region[RegionIntersection[Tetrahedron[coords], 
    HalfSpace[{.16, 0, .02}, c], BaseStyle -> Blue]], 
  PlotRange -> 1], {c, 0.001, .15}]
```

[image]